# how do I get rid of the single quotes around my string

Tags: shell, variables, command, zsh, command-substitution

I have a zsh script. There is a function ...

```
imgPrep()
{
local inFilePath=$1
local outFilePath=$2
local cropHeight=$3
local resize=$4
shift; shift; shift; shift
local options=$@

convert ${inFilePath} -crop 0x${cropHeight}+0+0 +repage -resize ${resize}% ${options} ${outFilePath}
}
```

I call the function like so:

```
IMoptions="-despeckle -unsharp 0x3+1+0"
imgPrep ${inputImgFilePath} ${headerImgFilePath} ${headerHeight} ${scale} ${IMoptions}
```

convert command fails , presumably because single quotes should not be there.

```
convert somefile.jpg -crop 0x60+0+0 +repage -resize 410% '-despeckle -unsharp 0x3+1+0' output.tif

convert: unrecognized option `-despeckle -unsharp 0x3+1+0' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1437
```

How do I fix this please?

Comment: It would have worked in your case if you had used `${(z)IMoptions}` instead of `$IMoptions`, but of course it is a better idea to use an array for passing those options.

Comment: You can use `shift 4` instead of calling `shift` 4 times.

Comment: Or you can use `${@:5}` and not worry about using `shift` at all.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by using an array

```
local options=("$@") # Store options in an array

convert ${inFilePath} -crop 0x${cropHeight}+0+0 +repage -resize ${resize}% "${options[@]}" ${outFilePath}
```

...

```
imgPrep ${inputImgFilePath} ${headerImgFilePath} ${headerHeight} ${scale} "${IMoptions[@]}"
```

Thank you Daniel Kelley for providing the correct answer. Luckily, I caught it before it was deleted, which is a shame.

Comment: You don't really need an array; you can just use `"$@"` directly instead of trying to assign it to a new name in the first place. `imgPrep ... "$@" ${outFilepath}`.

Comment: @chepner good to know. You should have made it an answer instead of a comment.